# Are there undocumented changes in the classpath in Java 7

Tags: classpath, java-7

I used to do the following command line in Java 6:

java -cp "d:\mylib\*" com.my.package.program

Now I upgraded to JDK 7 u1 64 bit and it started to complain that a jar can not be found. The jar IS in the mylib folder.

I looked in http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

There is nothing specific written for Java 7. But is the info there up to date?

Answer (score 5):

Java 7 single entry classpaths under windows seem to be broken. To work around this issue I split my classpath, because for some odd reason, java 7 classpaths under windows do work if they consist of 2 or more entries.

For example:

```
java -cp "d:\mylib\*;d:\myLib" com.my.package.program
```

or even

```
java -cp "d:\mylib\*;" com.my.package.program
```

would work with java 7. I am aware that this is by no means a very elegant solution, but at least the programs run.